# Define variables in different orders cause crash

Tags: c++, crash, initialization, class-members

My program crashes if I change the order the variables defines, anybody knows why?
In this order it will run as I expect:

```
class xThread
{
public:  
    xThread();
    virtual ~xThread() {}

    bool thread_start();
    virtual bool thread_init(){return true;}
    virtual void thread_stop();

    void thread_setState(ThreadState s) {state = s;} 
    ThreadState thread_getState( ){return state;}

    static void *thread_run(void *param);
    void setName(const char *n);
    char name[MAX_NAMESIZE];

protected:
    volatile ThreadState state;
    virtual void thread_proc()=0;

private:
    pthread_t pid;
};
```

If I change the define order of the variables "name" and "state", it will crash:

```
class xThread
{
public: 
    xThread();
    virtual ~xThread() {}

    bool thread_start();
    virtual bool thread_init(){return true;}
    virtual void thread_stop();

    void thread_setState(ThreadState s) {state = s;} 
    ThreadState thread_getState( ){return state;}

    static void *thread_run(void *param);
    void setName(const char *n);

protected:
    volatile ThreadState state;
    virtual void thread_proc()=0;

private:
    pthread_t pid;
    char name[MAX_NAMESIZE];
};
```

Here is the gdb stack,it looks strange

```
0  0x00007f34dfaeff72 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
1  0x00007f34dfaf187c in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
2  0x00007f34e03aa0cd in operator new(unsigned long) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
3  0x00007f34e15d93b1 in log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::string const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const () from /lib64/liblog4cxx.so.10
4  0x000000000081e615 in xServer::v_final (this=0x19921b0) at xlib/xServer.cpp:112
5  0x000000000082218c in xServer::run (this=0x19921b0) at xlib/xServer.cpp:411
6  0x00000000007b2ebc in main (argc=4, argv=0x7fff46d5f258) at SceneServer.cpp:152
```

"name" is a variable I used to lable each thread.It is defined before the thread started,and it is printed when the thread terminateed.

main.cpp:

```
    HttpClientThread client;
    client.setName("HttpClientThread ");
    client.thread_start();
```

xThread.cpp:

```
xThread::xThread()
{
    thread_setState(THREAD_INIT);
    bzero(name, sizeof(name));
    pid = 0;
}

xThread::~xThread()
{
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(::log4cxx::Logger::getLogger("main"), name);
}

void xThread::setName(const char *n) 
{
    if (!n) return;
    bzero(name, sizeof(name));
    strncpy(name, n, MAX_NAMESIZE-1);
}

bool xThread::thread_start()
{
    if (!thread_init()) return false;

    int ret = pthread_create(&pid, NULL, &thread_run, (void *)this);
    if (ret == 0)
    {   
        return true;
    }   
    else
    {   
        return false;
    }   
}

void xThread::thread_stop()
{
    if (thread_getState()==THREAD_INIT)
        thread_setState(THREAD_FINISH);

    if (thread_getState()==THREAD_RUN)
        thread_setState(THREAD_STOP);
}

void *xThread::thread_run(void *param)
{
    xThread *t = (xThread *)param;
    t->thread_proc();
    t->thread_setState(THREAD_FINISH);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you post output of the debugger, gdb and or small working example ?

Comment: This depends on how `xThread()` is defined w.r.t. the initialization. Possibly `name[]` is being used there by some variable which is declared before it. Post the definition of constructor(s).

Comment: Do you own the source code for xThread.cpp and compile it in your project? Or are you just using a library and the posted snippet (the one you are trying to modify) is a copy of from a header distributed with the library?

Comment: Note that `volatile` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @molbdnilo Since you are so almost sure, what do you think he thinks `volatile` mean? (what assumption do you make about what he thinks `volatile` mean)

Comment: Constructor is like this,   xThread::xThread()
{
    bzero(name, sizeof(name));
    thread_setState(THREAD_INIT);
    pid = 0;
}

Comment: Most likely: You have an off-by-one error in your use of `name`. With `name` defined before `pid` the result is that you partially overwrite `pid`. With `name` defined after `pid` the result is that you write past the data block allocated for `xThread`, which `malloc` detects and complains about. Are you doing `name[MAX_NAMESIZE]=0;` when you mean `name[MAX_NAMESIZE-1]=0;` perhaps?

Comment: @Erik ,I changed the constuctor like this,it still crashed.xThread::xThread()
{
    thread_setState(THREAD_INIT);    pid = 0;
    name[MAX_NAMESIZE]=0;
    bzero(name, sizeof(name));

}

Comment: A situation like this is consistent with linking with objs/against libs compiled with the older definition. If all the source code is under your control, `make clean; make` (and, if problem disappear, have a look over the compile dependencies). If you are trying to modify the header of an existing library, shame on you. If neither of the above helps, then the bug may be in some other place and only triggered by this change.

Comment: @Erik,I fixed it like this:name[MAX_NAMESIZE-1]=0;

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi,I wrote all the code,it used a third lib "log4cxx" like the gdb shows."make clean" did't help because I have done it for many times.

Comment: Show us every piece of code that accesses `name`

Comment: @WenJuanWu then be prepared to accept the bug may be in a total different place and this change of member declaration order created the condition for that bug to be fatal (valgrind pops in mind for diagnosis of heap corruptions)

Comment: @Erik, I put it after the gdb infos

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi,Thank you,I'll try it

Comment: let's see the definition of `setName` - where you write to `name`. Also, what is the value of `MAX_NAMESIZE`?

Comment: @Erik,MAX_NAMESIZE is a macro definition,#define MAX_NAMESIZE 64

Comment: Your use of `name` is not the problem - you will have to (like you should have done from the start) provide complete code.

Comment: @Erik,I post the whole cpp file.

Comment: The error is not in the posted code.

Comment: @Erik,The whole project have tens of thousands of lines,sorry I could't post then all.May be the bug is caused by other code,Thanks for your help.

Comment: As @AdrianColomitchi said - use valgrind.

Answer (score -1):

You've changed not only order. Name became private. I cannot see any usage of "name" in this class. Should it be protected at least?

Comment: There's no way that changing that will cause a crash.

Comment: @VladimirBarshak You should gain enough rep and post such as a comment.

Comment: @VladimirBarshak, GDB only shows the main thread, but I create more then 20 threads, and I don't know which one cause the crash